# Side bar scrolling on fiore theme

Tags: css, scroll

I'd like to have a scroll bar on the right menu that floats out from the lined icon on the top left side. Can you tell me what and where to add code in the css, please?

The site is theuniversalasian.com.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this css

```
#secondary {
    background: url("images/polkadots-2x.png") repeat scroll 0 0 / 10px auto #F7F7F7;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    height: 100%;
    left: -284px;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: scroll;
    padding: 25px 20px 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 190px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I was wondering if you can see the very last word on the side menu? I can only see the top part of it and want to be sure that all of the menu is visible...

Comment: use  padding: 25px 20px 0; in #secondary div css

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I don't know what that means.... Where does the padding go?